# Block many wrong requests via PHP

Tags: php, api, fail2ban

I have an API that requires a security token to run.
Is it possible to use Fail2Ban or ModEvasive to block access from IPs that often try to access the API with an incorrect token?

I use PHP to receive these requests, is it possible with it to inform Fail2Ban or ModEvasive that the user's IP should be blocked (temporarily), for example, after 10 failed attempts?

Comment: Yes, fail2ban can be used for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If such an abusive token usage is logged in log-file or journal from your application (API) you can use fail2ban to ban them.
Here is an example for log-file:

```
[my-php-app]
ports = http,https
backend = auto
logpath = /var/log/path-to-my.log
datepattern = ^{DATE}
failregex = ^\s*<ADDR>\s+\S+\s+Incorrect token used\.
maxretry = 10
findtime = 30m
bantime = 1h
```

For systemd journal you have to set `backend` to `systemd` (and proper value for `journalmatch`, see the [man pages](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/fail2ban/jail.conf.5.en.html#FILTER_FILES_(filter.d/*.conf)) or fail2ban's default filters for example).

This would match messages illustrated by following test and ban for 1 hour all intruders doing that after 10 attempts occurred in 30 minutes.

```
$ msg="$(date +%FT%T) 192.0.2.1 - Incorrect token used. (more info here ...)"
$ fail2ban-client -d '^{DATE}' "$msg" '^\s*<ADDR>\s+\S+\s+Incorrect token used\.'

Running tests
=============

Use      datepattern : ^{DATE} : Default Detectors
Use   failregex line : ^\s*<ADDR>\s+\S+\s+Incorrect token used\.
Use      single line : 2021-06-11T17:00:03 192.0.2.1 - Incorrect token us...


Results
=======

Failregex: 1 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [1] ^\s*<ADDR>\s+\S+\s+Incorrect token used\.
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [1] ^ExYear(?P<_sep>[-/.])Month(?P=_sep)Day(?:T|  ?)24hour:Minute:Second(?:[.,]Microseconds)?(?:\s*Zone offset)?
`-

Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 1 matched, 0 missed
[processed in 0.00 sec]
```

If you has different logging format you must adjust `failregex` (and possibly `datepattern`).

---

Newer version of fail2ban allows direct notification from application using fail2ban-API (via client or direct via pickle protocol to unix-socket), see [GH/fail2ban/fail2ban#2559 (comment)](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2559#issuecomment-548851675).
Prerequirements for this - your php-fpm user is able to write to `/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock`.